# Is there a non-grammatical reason why יִשְמָעֵאל is written with the tzeirei under the ayin and not under the aleph?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, yishmael

The word יִשְמָעֵאל is written with the tzeirei under the ayin and not under the aleph (like this: יִשְמָעאֵל). I think that the suffix אֵל refers to Hashem and therefore would have expected  the tzirei to be under the aleph.

Is the positioning of the tzeirei intended to convey some message or is it just the result of some grammatical rule?

Comment: The  alef is perhaps entirely silent

Comment: @kouty Not perhaps. It is entirely silent. Like the Alef in בראשית. It's still fair to ask for Midrash on this, though.

Comment: The alef is not silent. As he mentioned, ישמעאל is made of ישמע and אל (simultaneously, may g-d hear me) and is pronounced like it's base word (try to pronounce it with throat-ayin).

Comment: @uriel the Alef is completely silent. You could omit it in the spelling and the word would sound the same.

Comment: Incidentally, דניאל has this as well, with the tzeiri under the yud instead of the alef.

Comment: @iKay And יחזקאל

Comment: @iKay Interestingly, in Ezekiel 14:14 and 14:20, דניאל has a tzeirei under the aleph.

Answer (score 3):

I heard in a Torah Way shiur from Rabbi Yonasan Hughes that it is because the ayin stands for the eye which sees sheker lies and Yishmael represents serving G-d with lies. Here is the audio of the shiur: http://torahway.org.uk/archive/mp3/11-07-2012.mp3

Comment: +1 addresses the question. This point is found at minute ten.

Comment: Well found! Trouble is we now have to explain דניאל and יחזקאל too ...